# Android listView Listener slow in firing

Tags: java, android, performance, listener

I am using an array adapter and an onItemClickListener
I try to load a spinning dialog when something is clicked however its slow in reacting (more than 1 second load time from click to listener is triggered)

here is some code

```
    mainActivity.listViewToDisplay
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
```

Help?

Comment: Are you setting the listener on a different class from where the listview is shown?

Comment: Are you using ProgressDialog ? Post your code what you do when onItemClick